# Python Function Caching?

Tags: python, function, caching, return

I have encountered a very weird situation in Python.

I have a `while True:` loop in a script that constantly grabs real-time data. The data is only meant to be grabbed during business hours, therefore I have a helper function in a module called `lib/date.py`.

This is the function:

```
def isTime(utc_now=datetime.datetime.utcnow()): 
    '''
    9:00 AM UTC - 5:00 PM UTC Mon - Fri.

    The parameter utc_now can be used to specify a specific     
    datetime to be checked instead of the utcnow(). 
    '''

    week_day = utc_now.weekday()

    # no good on Saturdays and Sundays
    if 5 == week_day or 6 == week_day:
        return False

    now_int = (utc_now.hour * 60) + utc_now.minute

    if (17 * 60) >= now_int >= (9 * 60):
        return True

    return False
```

I realize that the way times are checked is an overkill, but this is a simplified version of my function. My real function also includes a bunch of time zone conversions which make the above necessary.

This is my main script (simplified):

```
def main():
    while True:
        do_ten_seconds()

def do_ten_seconds():
    log.info("alive")

    for i in xrange(10):   
        if isTime():
            log.info("its time")
            # do data grabbing
        sleep(1)
```

This works perfectly during the week, stopping every week night and continuing the next morning. However, on the weekend, it does not "recover" from the long break. In other words, `isTime` never returns `True` Monday morning.

I checked the log, and the script just prints "alive" every 10 seconds, but the data grabbing part never happens (and "its time" is never printed). Hence, I am assuming this means `isTime` is returning `False`.

Could it be that because the function is called so frequently over the weekend, and because it returns `False` so many times in a row, Python caches the results and never recovers from it?

When I spawn the same instance of code while the main script is still running in the faulty mode where `isTime` is returning `False`, the new instance gets `True` from `isTime` and begins to work perfectly.

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default arguments are calculated at **compile time**. Make the default value `None`, and check for that using `is None`.

Answer (score 5):

The first time you import date.py, the following line is run once:

```
def isTime(utc_now=datetime.datetime.utcnow()):
```

When it's run, the default value for `utc_now` is set to the time at that instant, and is never recomputed.